# Create automatic restore point of SQL using MVC

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am just thinking of this idea - if it is possible to have a restore button in my MVC application that will automatically take my SQL database back to a point in time before a problem was noticed in my web application. Just like in Windows. Is there a way to achieve this please?

Comment: Why would you do this? Why would you lose (or throw away) the data that was stored in between the last backup and the time the restore button was clicked. What if there are some important transactions/activities that have occurred between these events. This is where logging comes in. You log the errors/problems and rectify them. ***Your approach seems to running away/hiding the problems of the system instead of rectifying/improving them***. This isn't a good approach.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I am trying to run away from the problem. and that is because the application I have in mind is already running and was developed without reverse mechanism in mind. Taking from your advice, I should redefine my problem and approach to it.

Comment: The problem seams to be due to relationship among the tables that prevents manipulating some records after entering data against at least one of the entities. Specifically, a class of student in FirstTable  while SecondTable holds the scores. so when score is entered for one student for the first time, the others get zero until the field is edited with their actual score. At this stage, no student can be deleted. So can I have a drop down list for ClassName in FirstTable, and a clear button for scores of the selected class in my MVC View? Or is there a better approach to handle this. Thanks.